# How to specify positional arguments with the flag package in Golang?

Tags: go

Sometimes I want to pass an argument on the command line with no name, say a command like `wc`, which takes a filename as input:

```
wc filename.txt
```

With the [flag package](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/), it looks like every flag has to be given a name, with a default value if unspecified.

```
filename := flag.String("filename", "foo.txt", "Which file to count the words for")
```

However I don't want a default value, I want the program to exit with an error code if an argument is not specified. How would I add a required argument to a Go binary?

I would also like to be able to parse arguments with type information, so just checking the Args() directly doesn't quite do it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just have to check `flag.NArg()`.

From https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#NArg:

> NArg is the number of arguments remaining after flags have been processed.

```
flag.Parse()
if flag.NArg() == 0 { 
    flag.Usage()
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean that you can't enforce types on positional arguments then?

Comment: `Usage` is a variable that holds a function. You can find it here. https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#pkg-variables

Comment: I don't see how the `flag.Usage()` function can give helpful output with positional arguments, as I can't find a way to "register" them. I've expanded on this more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873183/how-to-print-usage-for-positional-argument-with-gos-flag-package

Comment: Be warned: this is sensitive to the order of positional args vs flags.
Ex: outp := flag.String("output", "out.txt", "Output file")
Shell: myProgram positional_arg.txt -output redirect.txt # *outp = "out.txt", flag.NArg() = 3

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the flag.Narg() function to ensure you have the required number of positional arguments, though I don't know what it gives you over len(flag.Args())

```
if flag.NArg() < minArgs { 
    // do something
    ...
}
```

Comment: From the [flag package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/flag) : << After parsing, the arguments following the flags are available as the slice `flag.Args()` or individually as `flag.Arg(i)`. The arguments are indexed from `0` through `flag.NArg()-1`.>>

Comment: Beware though, all flags after the first positional flags are treated as positional. So `go run main arg1 --flag1=1 --flag2=2` will actually show as flag.NArg() == 3, and dashed flags won't be parsed but will show up as positional. Golang is a mess.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is unsatisfied with the standard `flag` package behavior of stopping the parse as soon as it sees the first positional arg, you can use these small library functions to parse flags in a way that flags can come before or after positional args.

```golang
// ParseFlags works like flag.Parse(), except positional
// args and flag args can be specified in any order.
func ParseFlags() error {
    return ParseFlagSet(flag.CommandLine, os.Args[1:])
}

// ParseFlagSet works like flagset.Parse(), except positional
// args and flag args can be specified in any order.
func ParseFlagSet(flagset *flag.FlagSet, args []string) error {
    var positionalArgs []string
    for {
        if err := flagset.Parse(args); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // Consume all the flags that were parsed as flags.
        args = args[len(args)-flagset.NArg():]
        if len(args) == 0 {
            break
        }
        // There's at least one flag remaining and it must be a positional arg since
        // we consumed all args that were parsed as flags. Consume just the first
        // one, and retry parsing, since subsequent args may be flags.
        positionalArgs = append(positionalArgs, args[0])
        args = args[1:]
    }
    // Parse just the positional args so that flagset.Args()/flagset.NArgs()
    // return the expected value.
    // Note: This should never return an error.
    return flagset.Parse(positionalArgs)
}
```