# How to print usage for positional argument with Go's flag package?

Tags: go

Given this simple Go program, which requires exactly one command line argument, how can I improve it so that `flag.Usage()` gives useful output?

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if len(flag.Args()) == 0 { 
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    args := flag.Args()
    fmt.Println(args[0])
}
```

Current output with no arguments given:

```
$ ./args
Usage of ./args:
```

(i.e. usage is empty, as I can find no way to tell the usage() function which parameters are required).

I can remove `flag.Usage()` and replace it with something like this:

```
fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Usage:", os.Args[0], "<argument>")
```

However, I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's already a good way with `flag.Usage()`. Especially as it's already handling optional arguments:

```
$ ./args -foo
flag provided but not defined: -foo
Usage of ./args:
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`flag.Usage()` will only give you useful information about the defined flags. So you either define your arguments as flags via `var foo = flag.Int(...)`.

Another option would be to define your own usage handler. see below for a simple example which will print a custom message and the defaults for all defined flags. This way you custom `Usage` will be printed in case `flag.Parse()` fails.

```
package main
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func myUsage() {
     fmt.Printf("Usage: %s [OPTIONS] argument ...\n", os.Args[0])
     flag.PrintDefaults()
}

func main() {
     flag.Usage = myUsage
     /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'm not sure why Go can't define positional arguments, as I thought these would also be common. If I could define an argument with no name then I wouldn't need to create a custom `Usage()` function, the built-in function could handle it along with the others. Still your solution works well without much extra code. :)